# OS X Trouble with Semaphores

Tags: c++, xcode, semaphore

I'm having trouble with initializing semaphores, because sen_init doesn't seem to work in Xcode. When I tried using sen_init, the semaphore value would not increment or decrement when calling post/wait. Before anything though, Xcode provided a warning for sen_init, saying that it was deprecated.

After doing some reading, it seems that I need to use sen_open instead of sen_init. I've been spinning my wheels on it, because it keeps throwing an error: EXEC_BAD_ADDRESS when trying to get it created.

Why does sem_open not work similar to init? What do I need change to get it to function properly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
using namespace std;

sem_t full, empty;
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_t tid;
pthread_mutex_t t_mutex;

void initStates(){
    full = *sem_open("full", 0, 0);
    empty = *sem_open("empty", 0, 5);

    sem_init(&full, 0,0);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, 5);
    pthread_mutex_init(&t_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    initStates();
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used these calls before, but I took a quick look at the [`sem_open` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sem_open.2.html), and it looks like you need to have the second argument, `int oflag`, set to something that isn't `0`. You probably want to set it to `O_CREAT`.

Then, you'll need two more arguments, `mode_t mode` and `unsigned int value`. `mode` should be something like `S_IRWXU` (see the [`chmod` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/chmod.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/chmod)), and `value` should be whatever starting value you want for the given semaphore.